# PHP: getting "SSA&#039;s" instead of "SSA's"

Tags: php, html, apache

Im having a problem displaying certain data with PHP from the database.

How its currently showing - "SSA&#039;s"

How it should show "SSA's"

HTML Meta Tag

```
meta charset="UTF-8">
```

PHP Code

```
$article_title = html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding(stripslashes($r->ArticleTitle), "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Is the meta tag incomplete or just a typo?

Comment: It sounds like maybe it is double encoded, if you view the source does it show `SSA&amp;#039;s` ?  you shouldn't need to call stripsplashes on it.

Comment: If i view the source i get SSA&amp;#039;s

Comment: So you're needlessly *encoding* to HTML entities somewhere along the line more than once.

Comment: Ok its fixed the issues when displaying the data in the page. although its only the search bar now that displays the incorrect title. i have a jquery function that takes the title and uses it as a placeholder in the value of the search input. could the jquery.val() function be causing an issue reading the format of the article title ?

Comment: `.val()` displays the value *as is*, while a string with HTML entities *embedded in HTML* causes the entities to be interpreted. The issue is still the same: you have needless HTML entities in your string. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: @deceze Thank you for that. i have fixed the issue within the search input.

Comment: What fixed the issue? Please accept the answer using the checkbox if it resolves your issue (the checkbox is the thing below the down vote)

Comment: Thanx @ChrisBanks wasnt aware of that feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `decode` by using these two methods `html_entity_decode()` or `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

**Basic Example:**

```
$string = html_entity_decode("SSA&#039;s");
echo $string; // result SSA's

$string = htmlspecialchars_decode("SSA&#039;s");
echo $string; // result SSA's
```

Comment: $string = htmlspecialchars_decode("SSA&#039;s");
echo $string;

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `html_entity_decode` function, as you are double encoding HTML-ENTITIES

And as @ChrisBanks pointed out, you also don't need `stripslashes`

Comment: If it's double encoded, he actually needs to call `html_entity_decode` again.. kind of strange data issue.

Comment: May depend on how he is echo'ing `$article_title` - don't have enough information yet to know.

Comment: @ChrisBanks yes, he would need to give us feedback if that helped

Comment: @ChrisBanks i store the ArticleTitle into the variable $article_title and push it to the html page using Twig. i then call the value using {{article_title | raw}}

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `html_entity_decode` again because the data is being stored as double encoded and remove the `stripslashes`.

```
$article_title = html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode(mb_convert_encoding($r->ArticleTitle, "HTML-ENTITIES", 'UTF-8')));
```

You might want to investigate how the data is being stored in the database as double-encoded in the first place.  Perhaps `htmlentities` is being called twice somewhere.

To add on to the comment:

You shouldn't store data HTML encoded unless for some reason you really and truly need to (there might be some cases you're required to).  It is only on output and rendering on a webpage do you want to use `htmlentities`.

Comment: `htmlentities` shouldn't be called on save anyway. It should be used for the output, but not to save inputs.